# forcing page load on an AJAX-loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ipad, onload

I have an issue with an third-party integration on an iPad-specific website, which has a number of pages loaded via AJAX.

When I go to the page for the first time the functionality that is expected to be available is not, and only when I do a page refresh in Safari do I see the feature.

In the 3rd party JavaScript there is this sort of code peppered throughout:

```
script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () { // do something }
```

Here is the [full JavaScript included file](https://services.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/js/captureplus-1.31.js?key=we84-cn95-ub48-pc25&app=4565).

Is there a way that I can either force a page load on the iPad or build in some workaround that means that when I change to the page where the JavaScript is included and fires?

As I mentioned, this is only apparent on an iPad-specific website and the same feature has no problem on a desktop browser where the page is *not* loaded via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

i believe web servers allow you to add content dynamically for all pages rendered using the web server. which allows you to insert a code snippet which can ideally check if its a ipad website and do page load as you requested.

follow the below thread

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/e27f918e-89a9-45a8-8604-2ad2ded09d64.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I'm not sure this really helps me to be honest. I'm quit familiar with adding a footer to a webpage, but this is a JavaScript/AJAX really.

Comment: well the footer can have a javascript injected

Comment: My JavaScript has to be placed inline, within the form for it to function so it is not possible to place the JavaScript in the footer unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your code looks like, but, having experienced the same issues repeatedly with jQuery, I would suggest you manually call the initialize function of the 3rd party script within a window ready state function:

```
$(window).ready(function(e) {
    // function that initializes the 3rd party script gets called here.
});
```

Comment: I have just updated the question with the JavaScript include file added. I just reference this on my page with `<script>` tags. I have no control over the third-party JavaScript file, so I cannot change their code in anyway. Where are you suggesting adding the `$(window).ready`?

Comment: In the page you reference the 3rd party script. So under the `<script>` tag where you reference this 3rd party plugin, just add `<script>$(window).ready(function(e) { capturePlus.init() });</script>`